# responsive layout design: items does not fit automatically in screen width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a wordpress site located at: http://evegroup.net .When I view this site in screen which are wide enought it looks like below:

[image]

However when screen is not wide enough elements in blog-section are not fitted in screen width and looks broken as below:

[image]

Here is the code of this section, which element need to be revised to fix this issue?

```
<div class="section-overlay blog-section-overlay" style="">
        <div class="mid-content">
            <div class="container">
                <h2>مطالب آموزشي</h2>
                <a class="blog-view-all" href="http://evegroup.net/category/%d9%88%d8%a8%d9%84%d8%a7%da%af/">مشاهده همه</a>
                <div class="blog-posts clearfix">
                    <div style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 2s; animation-delay: 1s; animation-name: slideInUp;" class="blog-post-wrap pull-left wow slideInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="1s">
                        <figure>
                            <img src="http://evegroup.net/wp-content/uploads/instant-apps-section-2-270x127.png" title="Instant App: امکانی جالب و جدید از اندروید" alt="Instant App: امکانی جالب و جدید از اندروید" class="img-responsive">
                            <div class="hover">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span class="outer">
                                        <span class="inner">
                                            Instant App: امکانی جالب و جدید از اندروید
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </figure>
                        <a href="http://evegroup.net/instant-app-%d8%a7%d9%85%da%a9%d8%a7%d9%86%db%8c-%d8%ac%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%a8-%d9%88-%d8%ac%d8%af%db%8c%d8%af-%d8%a7%d8%b2-%d8%a7%d9%86%d8%af%d8%b1%d9%88%db%8c%d8%af/">
                            <h3>Instant App: امکانی جالب و جدید از اندروید</h3>
                        </a>
                        <span class="published-date">
                            اردیبهشت ۳۰, ۱۳۹۵
                        </span>
                        <div class="blog-excerpt">
                            تا به حال نرم افزارهای بسیار متنوع و جالبی برای اندروید منتشر شده اند. اما نصب کردن یک نرم افزار برای امتحان کردن آن هم دنگ و فنگهای خاص خود…
                        </div>
                        <a href="http://evegroup.net/instant-app-%d8%a7%d9%85%da%a9%d8%a7%d9%86%db%8c-%d8%ac%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%a8-%d9%88-%d8%ac%d8%af%db%8c%d8%af-%d8%a7%d8%b2-%d8%a7%d9%86%d8%af%d8%b1%d9%88%db%8c%d8%af/" class="blog_read">بیشتر</a>
                    </div>
                    <div style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 2s; animation-delay: 1s; animation-name: slideInUp;" class="blog-post-wrap pull-left wow slideInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="1s">
                        <figure>
                            <img src="http://evegroup.net/wp-content/uploads/hand-drawn-instagram-logo-and-buttons_23-2147534325-270x127.jpg" title="بیست روش برای افزایش دنبال کنندگان در اینستاگرام" alt="بیست روش برای افزایش دنبال کنندگان در اینستاگرام" class="img-responsive">
                            <div class="hover">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span class="outer">
                                        <span class="inner">
                                            بیست روش برای افزایش دنبال کنندگان در اینستاگرام
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </figure>
                        <a href="http://evegroup.net/%d8%a8%db%8c%d8%b3%d8%aa-%d8%b1%d9%88%d8%b4-%d8%a8%d8%b1%d8%a7%db%8c-%d8%a7%d9%81%d8%b2%d8%a7%db%8c%d8%b4-%d8%af%d9%86%d8%a8%d8%a7%d9%84-%da%a9%d9%86%d9%86%d8%af%da%af%d8%a7%d9%86-%d8%af%d8%b1-%d8%a7/">
                            <h3>بیست روش برای افزایش دنبال کنندگان در اینستاگرام</h3>
                        </a>
                        <span class="published-date">
                            بهمن ۱۷, ۱۳۹۴
                        </span>
                        <div class="blog-excerpt">
                            اینستاگرام از شبکه‌های بسیار پر طرفدار و رایج اینترنت است. جایی که کاربران می‌توانند همدیگر را ملاقات کنند و از تجربیات یکدیگر استفاده کنند و یا تجربیات و خاطرات خود…
                        </div>
                        <a href="http://evegroup.net/%d8%a8%db%8c%d8%b3%d8%aa-%d8%b1%d9%88%d8%b4-%d8%a8%d8%b1%d8%a7%db%8c-%d8%a7%d9%81%d8%b2%d8%a7%db%8c%d8%b4-%d8%af%d9%86%d8%a8%d8%a7%d9%84-%da%a9%d9%86%d9%86%d8%af%da%af%d8%a7%d9%86-%d8%af%d8%b1-%d8%a7/" class="blog_read">بیشتر</a>
                    </div>
                    <div style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 2s; animation-delay: 1s; animation-name: slideInUp;" class="blog-post-wrap pull-left wow slideInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="1s">
                        <figure>
                            <img src="http://evegroup.net/wp-content/uploads/social_network_01-270x127.jpg" title="آمار شبکه های اجتماعی در سال ۲۰۱۲" alt="آمار شبکه های اجتماعی در سال ۲۰۱۲" class="img-responsive">
                            <div class="hover">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span class="outer">
                                        <span class="inner">
                                            آمار شبکه های اجتماعی در سال ۲۰۱۲
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </figure>
                        <a href="http://evegroup.net/%d8%a2%d9%85%d8%a7%d8%b1-%d8%b4%d8%a8%da%a9%d9%87-%d9%87%d8%a7%db%8c-%d8%a7%d8%ac%d8%aa%d9%85%d8%a7%d8%b9%db%8c-%d8%af%d8%b1-%d8%b3%d8%a7%d9%84-%db%b2%db%b0%db%b1%db%b2/">
                            <h3>آمار شبکه های اجتماعی در سال ۲۰۱۲</h3>
                        </a>
                        <span class="published-date">
                            دی ۱۳, ۱۳۹۴
                        </span>
                        <div class="blog-excerpt">
                            شبکه های اجتماعی هر روز بیش از پیش در زندگی افراد نفوذ می کنند و افراد هر روز بیشتر از قبل اطلاعات خود را در این شبکه ها با افراد…
                        </div>
                        <a href="http://evegroup.net/%d8%a2%d9%85%d8%a7%d8%b1-%d8%b4%d8%a8%da%a9%d9%87-%d9%87%d8%a7%db%8c-%d8%a7%d8%ac%d8%aa%d9%85%d8%a7%d8%b9%db%8c-%d8%af%d8%b1-%d8%b3%d8%a7%d9%84-%db%b2%db%b0%db%b1%db%b2/" class="blog_read">بیشتر</a>
                    </div>
                    <div style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 2s; animation-delay: 1s; animation-name: slideInUp;" class="blog-post-wrap pull-left wow slideInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="1s">
                        <figure>
                            <img src="http://evegroup.net/wp-content/uploads/internet-marketing-services2-270x127.png" title="هر سایت باید چه امکاناتی داشته باشد؟" alt="هر سایت باید چه امکاناتی داشته باشد؟" class="img-responsive">
                            <div class="hover">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span class="outer">
                                        <span class="inner">
                                            هر سایت باید چه امکاناتی داشته باشد؟
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </figure>
                        <a href="http://evegroup.net/%d9%87%d8%b1-%d8%b3%d8%a7%db%8c%d8%aa-%d8%a8%d8%a7%db%8c%d8%af-%da%86%d9%87-%d8%a7%d9%85%da%a9%d8%a7%d9%86%d8%a7%d8%aa%db%8c-%d8%af%d8%a7%d8%b4%d8%aa%d9%87-%d8%a8%d8%a7%d8%b4%d8%af%d8%9f/">
                            <h3>هر سایت باید چه امکاناتی داشته باشد؟</h3>
                        </a>
                        <span class="published-date">
                            دی ۹, ۱۳۹۴
                        </span>
                        <div class="blog-excerpt">
                            در بسيار از پروژه ها که تا به حال انجام داده ام. زمانيکه با مشتري صحبت ميکنم، مشتري هيچ تصوري از ويب سايت ندارد و اين وظيفه ما است که…
                        </div>
                        <a href="http://evegroup.net/%d9%87%d8%b1-%d8%b3%d8%a7%db%8c%d8%aa-%d8%a8%d8%a7%db%8c%d8%af-%da%86%d9%87-%d8%a7%d9%85%da%a9%d8%a7%d9%86%d8%a7%d8%aa%db%8c-%d8%af%d8%a7%d8%b4%d8%aa%d9%87-%d8%a8%d8%a7%d8%b4%d8%af%d8%9f/" class="blog_read">بیشتر</a>
                    </div>
                    <div style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 2s; animation-delay: 1s; animation-name: slideInUp;" class="blog-post-wrap pull-left wow slideInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="1s">
                        <figure>
                            <img src="http://evegroup.net/wp-content/uploads/data_center-270x127.jpg" title="هاست و دامین چیست؟" alt="هاست و دامین چیست؟" class="img-responsive">
                            <div class="hover">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span class="outer">
                                        <span class="inner">
                                            هاست و دامین چیست؟
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </figure>
                        <a href="http://evegroup.net/114-2/">
                            <h3>هاست و دامین چیست؟</h3>
                        </a>
                        <span class="published-date">
                            دی ۹, ۱۳۹۴
                        </span>
                        <div class="blog-excerpt">
                            هاست و دامین چیست؟ این سوالیست که اکثر افرادی که تازه با دنیای اینترنت آشنا شده‌اند و قصد راه‌اندازی وبسایت دارند برایشان مطرح می‌شود و اگر شما هم یک کاربر…
                        </div>
                        <a href="http://evegroup.net/114-2/" class="blog_read">بیشتر</a>
                    </div>
                    <div style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 2s; animation-delay: 1s; animation-name: slideInUp;" class="blog-post-wrap pull-left wow slideInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="1s">
                        <figure>
                            <img src="http://evegroup.net/wp-content/uploads/increase-battery-life-of-laptop2-270x127.png" title="۱۲نکته برای نگهداری و افزایش طول عمر لپ تاپ" alt="۱۲نکته برای نگهداری و افزایش طول عمر لپ تاپ" class="img-responsive">
                            <div class="hover">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span class="outer">
                                        <span class="inner">
                                            ۱۲نکته برای نگهداری و افزایش طول عمر لپ تاپ
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </figure>
                        <a href="http://evegroup.net/%db%b1%db%b2%d9%86%da%a9%d8%aa%d9%87-%d8%a8%d8%b1%d8%a7%db%8c-%d9%86%da%af%d9%87%d8%af%d8%a7%d8%b1%db%8c-%d9%88-%d8%a7%d9%81%d8%b2%d8%a7%db%8c%d8%b4-%d8%b7%d9%88%d9%84-%d8%b9%d9%85%d8%b1-%d9%84%d9%be/">
                            <h3>۱۲نکته برای نگهداری و افزایش طول عمر لپ تاپ</h3>
                        </a>
                        <span class="published-date">
                            دی ۹, ۱۳۹۴
                        </span>
                        <div class="blog-excerpt">
                            در این پست نکاتی را برای شما خواهیم گفت که با رعایت انها عمر لپ تاپ و وسایل وابسته به لپ تاپ خود را بهبود بخشیده و لپ تاپ شما…
                        </div>
                        <a href="http://evegroup.net/%db%b1%db%b2%d9%86%da%a9%d8%aa%d9%87-%d8%a8%d8%b1%d8%a7%db%8c-%d9%86%da%af%d9%87%d8%af%d8%a7%d8%b1%db%8c-%d9%88-%d8%a7%d9%81%d8%b2%d8%a7%db%8c%d8%b4-%d8%b7%d9%88%d9%84-%d8%b9%d9%85%d8%b1-%d9%84%d9%be/" class="blog_read">بیشتر</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below mentioned code in css:

```
.blog-post-wrap.pull-left:nth-child(3n+3) + .pull-left {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: It worked. May I ask what was wrong with my template and how does this CSS fix my problem?